# How to auto add blog post from Blogger to developer story

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, developer-story

The Developer story is pretty cool stuff. Can it auto fetch a new post from my blog (Blogger) post?

Comment: I don't think you're meant to list all blog posts you make, but instead highlight those you think stand out.

Comment: may be just the specific tags e.g. #Stackoverflow

Comment: @umitems thanks for the feedback and suggestion. I like the idea but it's not something we're going to prioritise right now. We may consider it in the future.